# client.startTyping is not a function (Discord.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a Discord bot using NodeJS and DiscordJS. However, when I try to use the `client.startTyping()` function, referring to https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/issues/440 and http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_client.html, it seems to return an error saying the function does not exist. How can I fix this?

https://pastebin.com/S25fiJaZ (full code)

```
client.startTyping(message.channel);
for (i = 0; i < (times + 1); i++) {
    message.channel.sendMessage(msg);
}
client.stopTyping(message.channel);
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: client.startTyping is not a function
    at Client.client.on (/home/ty/discordbot/index.js:68:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/home/ty/discordbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/home/ty/discordbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:102:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/home/ty/discordbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:325:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/home/ty/discordbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:288:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/ty/discordbot/node_modules/ws/lib/EventTarget.js:103:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:213:7)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because as the error message says, the client object has no function called `startTyping`. That function is in the text channel object as seen [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=startTyping). Also, `sendMessage` is deprecated. Use send instead.

```
message.channel.startTyping();
for (i = 0; i < (times + 1); i++) {
    message.channel.send(msg);
}
message.channel.stopTyping();
```

Answer (score 7):

In **discord.js V13** `TextChannel.startTyping()` and `TextChannel.stopTyping()` have been replaced by a singular `TextChannel.sendTyping()`. This method automatically stops typing after 10 seconds, or when a message is sent.
As seen in the [docs](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#textchannel) for updating to V13

Answer (score 2):

This is because `client` don't have the startTyping function, channels have the startTyping channel, so you can do:

```
message.channel.startTyping()
```

You can stop typing with .stopTyping() so you can do this too:

```
message.channel.stopTyping()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `startTyping` function should be called on the channel instead of the client:

```
message.channel.startTyping();
setTimeout(function(){
    message.channel.stopTyping();
    message.channel.send(msg);
}, times);
```