# Discord.JS ReferenceError: stopTyping is not Defined

Tags: node.js, sqlite, discord.js, commando

I'm trying to get our announce command to work but it keeps throwing the following error:

```json
@Nimbi, An error occurred while running the command: ReferenceError: stopTyping is not defined
You shouldn't ever receive an error like this.
Please contact Nimbi#4961.
```

Here is my `announce.js` code:

```js
const stripIndents = require('common-tags').stripIndents;
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
require('dotenv').config();

ANNOUNCE_CHANNEL_NAME = process.env.ANNOUNCEMENT_CHANNEL;
NEWS_CHANNEL_NAME = process.env.NEWS_CHANNEL;
MODLOG_CHANNEL_NAME = process.env.MODLOG_CHANNEL;

module.exports = class NewsCommand extends Command {
    constructor (client) {
      super(client, {
        name: 'announce',
        memberName: 'announce',
        group: 'mod',
        aliases: ['news', 'ann', 'a'],
        description: 'Make an announcement in the news channel',
        format: 'Announcement',
        examples: ['announce John Appleseed reads the news'],
        guildOnly: true,
        throttling: {
          usages: 2,
          duration: 3
        },
        args: [
          {
            key: 'body',
            prompt: 'What do you want me to announce?',
            type: 'string'
          }
        ],
        userPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],
        clientPermissions: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES']
      });
    }
  
    run (msg, {body}) {
      try {
        startTyping(msg);
  
        let announce = body,
          newsChannel = null;
  
        const announceEmbed = new MessageEmbed(),
          modlogChannel = msg.guild.settings.get('modLogChannel',
            msg.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === MODLOG_CHANNEL) ? msg.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === MODLOG_CHANNEL).id : null);
  
        if (msg.guild.settings.get('announcechannel')) {
          newsChannel = msg.guild.channels.find(c => c.id === msg.guild.settings.get('announcechannel'));
        } else {
          msg.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === 'announcements')
            ? newsChannel = msg.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === ANNOUNCEMENT_CHANNEL)
            : newsChannel = msg.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === NEWS_CHANNEL);
        }
  
        if (!newsChannel) throw new Error('nochannel');
        if (!newsChannel.permissionsFor(msg.guild.me).has(['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'])) throw new Error('noperms');
  
        newsChannel.startTyping(1);
  
        announce.slice(0, 4) !== 'http' ? announce = `${body.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${body.slice(1)}` : null;
        msg.attachments.first() && msg.attachments.first().url ? announce += `\n${msg.attachments.first().url}` : null;
  
        announceEmbed
          .setColor('#AAEFE6')
          .setAuthor(msg.author.tag, msg.author.displayAvatarURL())
          .setDescription(stripIndents`**Action:** Made an announcement`)
          .setTimestamp();
  
        newsChannel.msg.say(announce);
        newsChannel.stopTyping(true);
  
        if (msg.guild.settings.get('mod-logs', true)) {
          if (!msg.guild.settings.get('hasSentModLogMessage', false)) {
            msg.reply(oneLine` I can keep a log of moderator actions if you create a channel named **${MODLOG_CHANNEL_NAME}**
                          (or some other name configured by the ${msg.guild.commandPrefix}setmodlogs command) and give me access to it.
                          This message will only show up this one time and never again after this so if you desire to set up mod logs make sure to do so now.`);
            msg.guild.settings.set('hasSentModLogMessage', true);
          }
          modlogChannel && msg.guild.settings.get('mod-logs', false) ? msg.guild.channels.get(modlogChannel).msg.say('', {embed: announceEmbed}) : null;
        }
  
        stopTyping(msg);
  
        return msg.embed(announceEmbed);
  
      } catch (err) {
        stopTyping(msg);
  
        if ((/(?:nochannel)/i).test(err.toString())) {
          return msg.reply(`there is no channel for me to make the announcement in. Create channel named either ${ANNOUNCE_CHANNEL_NAME} or ${NEWS_CHANNEL_NAME}`);
        } else if ((/(?:noperms)/i).test(err.toString())) {
          return msg.reply(`I do not have permission to send messages to the ${ANNOUNCE_CHANNEL_NAME} or ${NEWS_CHANNEL_NAME} channel. Better go fix that!`);
        }
  
  
        return msg.reply(oneLine`An error occurred but I notified ${this.client.owners[0].username}
        Want to know more about the error? Join the support server by getting an invite by using the \`${msg.guild.commandPrefix}invite\` command `);
      }
    }
};
```

My `discord.js` version is: `^12.5.1`

My `discord.js-commando` version is: `^0.11.1`

My `node.js` version is: `^12.0.0`

I've already tried defining it with:

`const {startTyping, stopTypeing } = require('discord.js');`

and

`const {startTyping, stopTypeing } = require('util');`

however, both simply threw the `startTyping is not a function` error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `discord.js` doesn't export a `startTyping` function, nor does `uiutil` (typo? nor does `util`). You probably want `channel.startTyping()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751653/client-starttyping-is-not-a-function-discord-js

Comment: That throws the `Reference Error: channel is not defined` error. So apparently that doesn't work either. I may just have to nerf this one. I'm starting to think this specific code isn't compatible with `discord.js-commando` or at least doesn't work with my setup.... which sucks since it claimed to be build for use with `discord.js-commando`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: this is in discord.js@13 and onwards*

##### startTyping

```js
// like 101arrowz said, startTyping (or now sendTyping) is a method of the TextChannel, which you can get by msg.channel
message.channel.sendTyping()
```

Discord.js and commando (which is by the same people) works great, but if you have any problems I suggest you read the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) or ask at their discord server (they do actually help)